# Error while inserting data through node server

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to insert data through JSON body into MySQL server.
But inserted data is in undefined format.
I am not able to find by which cause it happening to the nodejs simple basic project?

**Mysql helper file**

```
var mysqlHelper = require('../common/mysqlconn');
function adduser(req, res) {
var data = req.body;
var query = "insert into user_master(name,phonenumber) values ('" + data.name + "','" + 
data.phonenumber + "')";

mysqlHelper.excecuteQuery(query, function (err, result) {
    if (err) {
        res.json({
            success: false,
            err: err
        })
    }
    else {
        res.json({
            success: true,
            message: "Record inserted successfully"
        })
    }
 })
}
```

**server.js file**

```
module.exports = {
adduser: adduser
}

var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var port = process.env.PORT || 5300; // used to create, sign, and verify tokens
var path = require('path');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
extended: false
}));
app.use(bodyParser.json({
limit: 1024102420,
type: 'application/json'
}));
var user = require('./route/user.route');
app.use('/', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')))
app.use('/user', user);
var server = app.listen(port);
console.log('Server running at http://localhost:' + port);
```

Comment: Welcome to SO..Can you print your `req.body`??

Comment: Also can you please print headers of your request?